Correct syntax to access array elements in structs?
First-year comp sci student, and first time posting on here.
I have a struct:
struct Student{
    string name;
    int studentID;
    int numTests;
    int *testScores = new int [TESTS]; //Access with <variableName>.*(testScores + 1), <variableName>.*(testScores + 2), etc.
    int avgScore;
};

I'm having trouble trying to figure out how to change the values in the array. I guess I can't figure out the syntax.
This is what I'm doing, am I on the right track?
cout << "How many tests did this student take: ";
cin >> numTests;

//iterate numTests amount of times through dynamic array
for (int i = 0; i < numTests; ++i)
{
    cout <<"Enter score #" << i + 1 << ": ";
    cin >> tempScore;
    newStudent.*(testScores + i) = tempScore;
}    

I'd appreciate any help in figuring out the right way to go about changing the arrays values.
I've tried not using the temp value, changing it to
cin >> newStudent.*(testScores + i);
along with
cin >> *newStudent.(testScores + i);
and a few other variations, but I can't seem to find out the correct way to go about it. Still new to working with the heap.

what you do you mean with "reference array" ? You have a pointer to in as member initilaized to point to first element of an integer array. There is no reference

Access with <variableName>.*(testScores + 1),... no please dont do that. You access elements via newStudent.testScores[index]. But you really shouldnt be doing any of this but use a std::vector

Haven't learned anything about vectors yet, i Keep hearing about them though. Im limited in my ability to use tools like vectors.
Also not super good with describing the issue so if i say reference I may mean something else, first year student still.

you need better learning material. Working with c-arrays isnt something you can guess your way along. There are too many pitfalls. Try https://stackoverflow.com/questions/388242/the-definitive-c-book-guide-and-list

Appreciate the reading material ill look into it, for now is there any easy way tog o about this?

why are you limited in using vectors?  Arrays are the super complicated ones that you need to stay away from. std::vector is something beginners can learn from day 1. It takes 5 minutes to learn how to write a correct small program with std::vector but you can spend a lifetime to struggle with c-arrays.

professor outlawed them in the instructions, but i also haven't learned them yet

@463035818_is_not_an_ai Many introductory CS professors forbid using things like vector until introduced.

I told you the easy way. Forget about Access with <variableName>.*(testScores + 1),...,and use [] like this newStudent.testScores[index]

@Dúthomhas because they are not teaching C++. Anyhow this isnt a CS class room. The question is about C++ not about how to fool students and teach them C while making them believe it was C++

@463035818_is_not_an_ai No, questions answered out of context have useless answers

@Dúthomhas the context is having a dynamic array as member. In that context std::vector is not out of context. I never claimed that "use std::vector" would be a complete answer. Nevertheless its a suggestion someone should make to OP

Just ordered Programming: Principles and Practice Using C++, really appreciate that reference!

In the meantime you can have a go at learncpp.com, also make sure to lookup cppreference for reference (and up-to-date examples). And finally read the C++ core guidelines (after reading your book maybe) to know how C++ is to be used today (which might be a bit different again from a few years back)

@NoahStromberg professor outlawed them in the instructions -- The std::vector has been officially part of the C++ library for 26 years now.  That is probably older than most people in your class.  In this day and age, it makes no sense to not teach vector early,  This is why many beginner programmers are leaving C++ and taking up python or some other language -- they don't have these restrictions -- they use what the language has to offer them, plus they get programs actually working properly much faster.

Firstly, "reference array" is a surprising way to describe testScores. The testScores data member in your struct has type "pointer to int" and presumably points to the first element in the array you have allocated with a new expression.
Secondly, you access elements in that array by doing
newStudent.testScores[i] = tempScore;
// which is equivalent to ...
*(newStudent.testScores + i) = tempScore;

You can also write
std::cin >> newStudent.testScores[i];

... bypassing the need for an extra local tempScore variable.
Further Notes

Why should C++ programmers minimize use of 'new'? (using std::vector here would be easier)
What's the problem with "using namespace std;"? (prefer std::cin)


Thank you, I knew I wasn't describing the issue right. I used tempScore to just test and see if there was any difference, it was just there by the time of post lol.

"Firstly, "reference array" is a surprising way to describe testScores" really sorry. I edited out the surpise from the question. I'll just stay out and leave it to you to roll back or change your answer.

There are several things you must be aware of when dealing with direct memory management (using new and delete) in C++.
Rule of 3/5/0
First, there is the Rule of Three/Five/Zero. Basically, if you new memory, you must also delete it, and you must handle it correctly when your class is copied/moved.
struct Student
{
    int * scores;  // This is a pointer (to an array)
    int   nscores;  // Number of elements used in that array

    Student();  // Constructor
    ~Student();  // Destructor
    Student( const Student & student );  // Copy constructor
    Student( Student && student );  // Move constructor
    Student & operator = ( const Student & student );  // Copy Assignment operator
    Student & operator = ( Student && student );  // Move Assignment operator
};

Student::Student()
{
    scores = new int[ NUM_TESTS ];  // allocate NUM_TESTS elements
    nscores = 0;
    ...
}

Student::~Student()
{
    delete [] scores;  // clean up!
}

Student::Student( const Student & student )
{
    // same as before, but COPY the data!
    scores = new int[ NUM_TESTS ];  // allocate NUM_TESTS elements
    for (int n = 0; n < student.nscores; n++)
        scores[n] = student.nscores[n];
    nscores = student.nscores;
}

Student::Student( Student && student )
{
    // MOVE the data instead!
    scores = student.scores;
    student.scores = nullptr;
    nscores = student.nscores;
    student.nscores = 0;
}

Student & operator = ( const Student & student )
{
    // And again, except that we already have an array of
    // test scores allocated so we only need to copy them
    for (int n = 0; n < student.nscores; n++)
        scores[n] = student.nscores[n];
    nscores = student.nscores;
    ...
    return *this;
}

Student & operator = ( Student && student )
{
    // and again, MOVE the data!
    nscores = student.nscores;
    student.nscores = nullptr;
    nscores = student.nscores;
    student.nscores = 0;
    return *this;
}

Array/Pointer type & Accesses
Notice how the type of the pointer-to-array is just a pointer:
  int * scores;
And that we access elements of the array the usual way:
  scores[2] = 12;
Using it
Make sure not to let the user (or any other part of the program) grow nscores to be > NUM_TESTS.
cout << "How many tests did this student take: ";
cin >> numTests;

if (numTests > NUM_TESTS)
{
    cerr << "too many! ack!\n";
    return 1;
}

//iterate numTests amount of times through dynamic array
for (int i = 0; i < numTests; ++i)
{
    cout <<"Enter score #" << i + 1 << ": ";
    cin >> tempScore;
    newStudent.scores[i] = tempScore;
}

Fixed-length arrays
If you know your array is always a fixed length (as it is in your example), you don’t actually have to dynamically-allocate it.
struct Student
{
    int scores[ NUM_TESTS ];
    int nscores;
};

You still need to properly initialize nscores in your constructor and take care not to overrun the end of the array, though.
This is obviously not how your assignment is designed, but it is good to know anyway.
Variable-sized array
I assume at some point you will be tasked with making the array bigger if needed. This requires yet another member value:
struct Student
{
    int * scores;             // array of test scores
    int   nscores;            // number of elements used in scores[]
    int   nscores_available;  // size of scores[] array
};

This will complicate things a little, but it will allow you to do things like create an populate a bigger array if the current one is too small.
In other words, you are exchanging the global constant NUM_TESTS for a local member value nscores_available, which can be changed, and may differ between different Students.
That is for later, though.
